# M2.3.2 - Search not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, catalogsearch, magento2.3.2

I am using Magento 2.3.2, but sometimes the default search bar does not work MySQL engine for the catalog search.

For example, I have a product called "Test product for Toyota".
When I search "Test product for Toyota", it does not display the result.
However, when I remove the "for" word from the search query "Test product Toyota", the result shows properly.

I have been struggling to get this work but I couldn't, do you know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean the cache
   Solving any problem you always start with the same action of cache flushing. For this, go to System > Cache management > Flush Magento Cache. If this doesn’t help, move to other points from our list.

→ Speed up your store by enabling Full Page Cache Warmer

2. Check search configurations
   Another common solution of a not-working search in Magento 2 stores is just setting up the right configurations. For this, navigate to Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search and set 1 in the Minimal Query Length line and 128 in the Maximum Query Length line.

Then enable search suggestions and set 2 in the Search Suggestions Count line. Don’t forget to save the changes and flush the cache.

3. Make data reindexing
   Sometimes you may get issues with the search if your Magento doesn’t index properly. So reindexing can help you with the problem. To do this, open System > Index management, then select all points with the mass action and choose Update on save form the Actions dropdown.
4. Add or set search by synonyms
   To make search results more relevant, you need to enable search by synonym functionality. For this, go to Marketing > SEO & Search > Search Synonyms. Next, click on the New Synonym Group button to create a new group of synonyms. In the opened page, specify the scope and enter the synonyms separating them by commas. Then save the changes and check the result on the frontend.

If the search by synonym is already on and your Magento 2 search still doesn’t work properly, double-check the configurations of synonym groups.

For more information about search by synonym, check the official Magento documentation.

Answer (score 0):

What's your search configuration :
Is it fulltext search ?

With full test search 3 letter are skipped by Mysql.

Suggestion :

1. Switch to elastic search.
2. Use attribute search weight.
3. Add additional search attributes and populate specific data.
4. avoid using description as an attribute in search. If still needed give it a very less weight.
5. Give higher weight to product name and category